# A lot of TIME_WAIT connections? - CentOS

Tags: linux, php, tcp

I have 4 web servers running php which saves sessions to a memcache over my private network. Today just about every hour I have my logs filled up with this error

```
ERROR - 2010-11-07 16:31:33 --> Severity: Notice  --> session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Server 10.xx.xx.xx (tcp 11211) failed with: Connection timed out (110) Session.php 212
```

I checked the memcache server and it doesn't have a lot of connections to it just a about 5 or so established connections, but when I check web3 server for an example it has 13446 connections in TIME_WAIT and about 6962 of those are port 11211. My question is, is this high number of time_waits causes my server to connection time out to the memcache server or is there something else I need to be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIME_WAIT can be a side effect of NATing or of firewall configuration, but in neither case does it generally represent an issue, although it may be a symptom of a bigger problem.  If you do in fact have a firewall separating the two machines, consider eliminating it.

Answer (score 0):

it is normal, you have not problems